# SQL: See how many items in a list, return a hit in a table (using LIKE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the sake of argument, say I'm looking for first names in a table.  And, the table is irregular - no pattern, some people have 2 names, some 3, some it's all run together, whatever.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)

FROM
    NAME_TABLE N

WHERE
   --the list
    N.NAME LIKE 'John%'
    OR N.NAME LIKE 'Mich%'
    OR N.NAME LIKE 'Rob%'
```

The above would give how many hits - maybe 70 or 70000, who knows.  But, what I really want is a response from 0-3.

i.e., how many of my search terms, get a hit in the table.

- I could just run the query and pull the entire table of hits, then 
  use Excel to get the answer.
- Or if in a more typical programming language, I could run a loop
  that has an x + 1 in it.

**But is there a way to do this directly in an SQL query?** Specifically T-SQL I guess...very specifically SQL Server 2008, but I'm kinda curious in general.

Comment: Please show us the exact output you want.

Comment: `CASE WHEN N.NAME LIKE 'John%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +` repeat three times.

Comment: Say if all 3 of my terms were found at least once in the table, then I'd want the output: 3.  If 2 were found: 2.

Comment: Fix the question.  Show example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, at least for me, but my magic crystall ball tells me, that eventually you are looking for something like this:

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('sys%',[name])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfSys
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('plan%',[name])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfPlan
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('spt_%',[name])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfSpt
FROM sys.objects;
```

Another approach was to do a

```
SELECT 'sys%' AS Pattern, COUNT(*) AS CountPattern 
FROM ... WHERE [name] LIKE 'sys%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'plan%',COUNT(*)
...
UNION ALL
...
```

This would return a list of all your counts in tabular form.

The third chance was to place all your search patterns into a table and use this table in a `CROSS JOIN` (similar idea then the `UNION` approach, but more flexible and more generic):

```
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @tblPattern TABLE(Pattern VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblPattern VALUES('sys%'),('plan%'),('spt_%'); 

SELECT p.Pattern
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN PATINDEX(p.Pattern,o.[name])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountPattern
FROM sys.objects AS o
CROSS JOIN @tblPattern AS p
GROUP BY p.Pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement for each name that resolves to 1 if the name `exists` in the table or 0 if it does not. Then just add them together and the result will be 0-3 i.e. the number of names that exist in the table.

```
select
    case when exists
    select 1 from name_table
    where name like 'John%'
    then 1 else 0 end
    +
    case when exists
    select 1 from name_table
    where name like 'Mich%'
    then 1 else 0 end
    +
    case when exists
    select 1 from name_table
    where name like 'Rob%'
    then 1 else 0 end
```